# How to select month in Symfony2 Form?

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I want to query some data in a month, so I wrote a form, add some fields, but I found that I can't select a month in Symfony2's `date`, I have searched it in SF and found this:

[show month number instead of month name on symfony2 formbuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24647099/show-month-number-instead-of-month-name-on-symfony2-formbuilder)

I was very happy~~
Unfortunately, I found that can't work, the error information is:

```
The "format" option should contain the letters "y", "M" and "d".
```

Perhaps the cause is the version of Symfony2, which I used is Version 2.5.x.

Code:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $school_id   = $this->user->getSchoolId();
    $classes     = $this->container->get('doctrine')->getRepository('ProjCoreBundle:TbBizClass')->findBySchoolId($school_id);
    $classes_arr = array(0 => 'All Classes');
    foreach ($classes as $class) {
        $classes_arr[$class->getClassId()] = $class->getClassName();
    }
    $builder->setMethod('GET');
    $builder->add('classId', 'choice', array(
        'choices' => $classes_arr,
    ));
    $builder->add('status', 'choice', array(
        'choices' => array(
            0                             => 'All',
            Checkroll::STATUS_ATTD_CASUAL => 'Casual',
            Checkroll::STATUS_ATTD_SICK   => 'Sick',
        ),
    ));
    $builder->add('createdAt', 'date', array(
        'format'          => 'MMM-yyyy',
        'years'           => range(date('Y'), date('Y')+12),
        'days'            => array(1),
        'empty_value'     => array('year' => '----', 'month' => '----', 'day' => false)
    ));
}
```

Comment: Post your `FormType` code please...

Comment: @Mr.Smith I already know how to do it but still thank you !

Comment: You have wrong format. `MMM-yyyy` is not valid format.

Comment: Make sure you post your answer if you've solved it yourself!

Comment: @frumious OKay, I will post it right now.

Answer (score 0):

I found this:

[Symfony 2: How to render date field without a day?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20674569/symfony-2-how-to-render-date-field-without-a-day)

Very nice answer!

Next is copied from his answer:

> You can do something like this in your twig file.

```
{{ form_widget(yourForm.month.month) }}
{{ form_widget(yourForm.month.year) }}
```